MSVC 2019 static analysis: C26434 function hides a non-virtual function - which is a constructor
I have a class template derived from another class template, derived from a third class template.  All have an empty default constructor, and an empty virtual destructor.
Using MSVC 2019, compiling for x64, c++17
When I run Visual Studio's built-in static analysis, I get the following 2 warnings:
Warning    C26434  Function 'Derived1<T,T,double>::Derived1<T,T,double>' hides a non-virtual function 'Base<T,T,double>::Base<T,T,double>'.
Warning    C26434  Function 'Derived2<T,T,double>::Derived2<T,T,double>' hides a non-virtual function 'Derived1<T,T,double>::Derived1<T,T,double>'.
Might be of note that I don't see them when compiling in Debug, only Release (/O2)
This also happens for a second existing class hierarchy.
I was not aware that it was even possible to hide a constructor, which could never be virtual to begin with?
Are these some weird false positives or is there something sinister going on?
#include <iostream>

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
class Derived1 : public Base<A,B,C>
{
public:
    Derived1() {}
    virtual ~Derived1() {}
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
class Derived2 : public Derived1<A,B,C>
{
public:
    Derived2() {}
    virtual ~Derived2() {}
};

class T {};

int main() {
    Derived2<T,T,double> d;
    std::cout << sizeof(d) << "\n";  // to prevent optimizing away the instantiation
    return 0;
}

https://godbolt.org/z/8P5ef7ahd

I added /analyze to your demo and selected a VS2019 version but it doesn't show the message you get.

Are you using the latest version? They did resolve some issues with this warning https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/c-core-check-false-positive-c26434/228085

What is your visual studio version?

VS Community 2019 - Version 16.11.thirysomething, which I then updated to 16.11.42 with no change.

VS 2022 does not occur the problem. Consider updating Visual Studio to 2022.
